# How to sort 2 indexes in python

Tags: pandas

I am trying to achieve some thing like the flowing result:

```
date      symbol    Open    High    low    close
2016-12-23  AAPL    804.6   809.9   800.5   809.1   
            CSCO    29.8    29.8    29.8    29.8
2016-12-27  AAPL    824.6   842.3   822.15  835.77  
            CSCO    29.32   29.9    29.3    29.85
```

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from iexfinance.stocks import get_historical_data
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
start =  '2014-01-01'
end = datetime.today().utcnow()
symbol = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']

out = pd.DataFrame()
datasets_test = []
for d in symbol:
    data_original = data.DataReader(d, 'iex', start, end)
    data_original['symbol'] = d
    data_original = data_original.set_index(['symbol'], append=True)
    out = pd.concat([out,data_original],axis=0) 
    out.sort_index()

print(out.tail(5))
```

and this is my outcome:

```
                     open    high       low   close    volume
date       symbol                                            
2019-02-11 MSFT    106.20  106.58  104.9650  105.25  18914123
2019-02-12 MSFT    106.14  107.14  105.4800  106.89  25056595
2019-02-13 MSFT    107.50  107.78  106.7100  106.81  18394869
2019-02-14 MSFT    106.31  107.29  105.6600  106.90  21784703
2019-02-15 MSFT    107.91  108.30  107.3624  108.22  26606886
```

I am trying to get a sort within the 2 indexes (date + symbol) and getting confused on the use of the sort

thanks!

Comment: df.sort_values(by=['date', 'symbol'])

Comment: KeyError: 'date'

Comment: what's the output for `out.index.names`

Comment: I would say the parameter `inplace=True` is missing from your `sort_index`, such as `out.sort_index(inplace=True)` to save in `out` the result of the sorted operation.

Comment: @Giladbi good, 2 more things, first using `pd.concat` and reassigning `out` in each loop is not the best practice especially if you do a lot of iterations, so the best would be to append all your data to a list and then use `out = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)` outside the loop. the other thing is that the lines `sort_index` as well as `set_index` can be done on `out` also outside of the loop, these should increase the efficiency of your code :)

Comment: thanks for the help!!